# Not getting data by axios.get() request in reactjs from spring boot backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I trying to fetch data from spring boot controller but the data not appeared in front side ReactJS.

Spring boot controller working fine in localhost and data also appeared in localhost.

Spring Boot Controller:

```
package com.javaguidestutorials.reactspringboot.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.javaguidestutorials.reactspringboot.model.Employee;
import com.javaguidestutorials.reactspringboot.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000/")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    // get all employees
    
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees()
    {
        
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
        
    }
    
    //Add employee
    
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee)
    {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee); 
    }
}
```

ReactJS Employee service:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/employees";

class EmployeeService{

    getEmployees(){

        return axios.get(EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL);
    }
}

export default new EmployeeService()
```

getEmployee function attached to EmployeeComponent:

```
componentDidMount(){
        EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res) => {
            this.setState({ employees : res.data });
        });
    }
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-springboot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-cookiejar-support": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "tough-cookie": "^4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Getting Error Like:

```
xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:9090/api/v1/employees 403
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:76
wrap @ bind.js:9
getEmployees @ EmployeeService.js:9
componentDidMount @ ListEmployeeComponent.jsx:20
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20663
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:646
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
./src/index.js @ index.js:19
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ Footer.css?f24e:82
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Spring Boot GET REST APIs working fine in post man:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKLpr.png)

Error in localhost:3000 in ReactJS:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXR71.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake.

Solution:

we need to enable CORS from server side so that we can fetch data from front side.

To Enable this we need to add one function in server side application.

I'm using spring boot so, you need to add this function in you main application class

```
@Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
      return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
          @Override
          public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
              registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
          }
      };
  }
```

See the whole main application class add function like this:

```
package com.javaguidestutorials.reactspringboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactSpringbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactSpringbootApplication.class, args);
    }

    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }
}
```